# How to change filtering type from LIKE to EQUAL in DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables

In a DataTable, if I write "AB" in the search box, it would return the rows which contain "AB" and also "ABC". I want it to return only the rows which contain "AB", not "ABC". How to change the settings in DataTables?

Answer (score 3):

try this in your code

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "search": {
    "smart": false
  }
} );
```

there are another way to solve your problem

```
oTable.fnFilter( "^"+TERM+"$", COLUMN , true);
```

Comment: I tried your first solution. It didn't work. After using it, it's still showing the row which contains "ABC" when I am writing "AB" in the search box.

Comment: and what is the value of TERM and COLUMN variable in your second solution?